# change ownership of each new file at google drive

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I need to transfer ownership of each new file of the whole domain to one specific admin user at Google Drive.
I found the action of ownership transfer, but cannot find how to trigger it from new file creation.

is it possible to transfer the ownership (or share) of each new file without permission request to the original owner and by default?

Answer (score 0):

If you were hoping to do it in one call thats not going to happen.

After you create the file do i [permissions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list)  This will return all the permissions on the file.   There should only be one.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions
```

Then taking the permission response from above Change the owner

And call a [permissions.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update) .

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions/permissionId
```

Make sure to `transferOwnership=True`